# Using an object of two Integers as key in Hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable

I am trying to use a key pair (eg: start, end) to save a list of recorded distances in a Hashtable. I then realised very quickly that what I was trying to do, a sample found in the following abstract shouldn't work

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Hashtable<test1, Integer> test = new Hashtable<test1, Integer>();
        test1 a = new test1(2, 3);
        test.put(a, 6);
        System.out.println(test.get(a)); //prints 6
        test1 b = new test1(2, 3);
        System.out.println(test.get(b)); //prints null
    }
}

class test1 {
    public int a, b;
    public test1(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

I understand that the Hashtable.get() function uses the reference as the object rather than the values inside, so I was wondering if there is a way to map a 2 variable key into the Hashtable or another possible solution such that getting the value from the Key,Value pair can be done in linear time.

Comment: Implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your key class

Comment: Hashtable is a legacy class that almost always should be avoided in favor of HashMap also.

Comment: Also, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are written in PascalCase, that means they start with uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

please try to make an .equals() method using @overide annotation in the test1 class. That should solve your problem. Check here for more information - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/